# Java net present value

Tags: java

I am trying to find the net present value after so many years at a fixed rate and when I run it I keep getting the negative sign of the number that I want but when I removed the negative in my last line the same problem occurs. When my code reads as

```java
public static double netPresentValue(double investment, int years, double payout, double r) {
    double count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i == years; i++) {
        investment =   presentValue(payout, i, r) - investment; 
    } 
    return -investment;
}
```

-90909 is expected but I get +90909
when I write

```java
public static double netPresentValue(double investment, int years, double payout, double r) {
    double count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i == years; i++) {
        investment =   presentValue(payout, i, r) - investment; 
    } 
    return investment;
}
```

for year zero I receive that the code should produce -100000 but I am getting 100000

Comment: I suggest stepping through your code with the debugger.

Comment: Id bet its your loop conditional. i == years will return false for the first iteration unless years == 1, and I don't know what your test cases are, but it doesn't sound like its 1.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the first year the only thing that happens is the debt is instantiated and you should start off with a negative investment and then add the new payout each year

```
public static double netPresentValue(double investment, int years, double payout, double r) {
    double debt = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= years; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
    debt = -investment; 
    }//
    else {
    debt = debt + presentValue(payout, i, r);
    }//end else
    }//end for loop 
    return debt;
    }
```